# Closure relations between Bruhat cells on the flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a Lie group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a Borel subgroup $B$. There is this famous Bruhat decomposition of the flag variety $G/B$.

How do we prove the closure relations between the cells, which are indexed by the Weyl group elements?

I was thinking about constructing a curve that connects two $T-$fixed points, using the exponential map. Let $e_{\alpha}$ be a root in the Lie algebra. How do we think about the action of $\exp(t \cdot e_{\alpha})$ on $G/B$, as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place I've read about this is in the paper "Schubert cells, and the cohomology of the spaces $G/P$" by Berstein, Gelfand, and Gelfand.  The flag variety can be identified with the projectivization of a representation of $G$, $V_{\lambda}$.  Then you compute the limit of the 1-psg $exp(t\cdot e_{\alpha})$ as it acts on weight vector $v_{w\lambda}$. As $t\to \infty$, you get $v_{s_{\alpha}w\lambda}$.

Comment: The three authors (then in Moscow) also known as BGG were Joseph Bernstein together with his teacher Israel Gelfand and  Gelfand's son Sergei.  The paper is available online in Russian: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=4887&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 3):

For a first introduction you can read Michel Brion's "http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410240v1.pdf". He gives a nice introduction (for G=GL(n)) in Section 1.

I'm not sure whether your curve method works but your strategy is similar to that in this question: [Is there a Morse theory proof of the Bruhat decomposition?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28569/is-there-a-morse-theory-proof-of-the-bruhat-decomposition).